# Select Check Boxes in ListView[( Select multiple checkbox but one by one), Select All at once, Select only one at a time]

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, custom-lists

I have to Select Check boxes in ListView. Right now when I am selecting the  checkbox, some check boxes below got checked automatically. 
    This is my code:

**StudentAdapter.java:**

```
public class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Activity activity;
private List<StudentBean> studentBeanList;
private boolean checked = false;
CheckBox checkBox;
public StudentAdapter(Activity activity, List<StudentBean> studentBeanList){
    super();
    this.studentBeanList = studentBeanList;
    this.activity = activity;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return studentBeanList.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return studentBeanList.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    StudentAdapter.ItemHolder itemHolder= new StudentAdapter.ItemHolder();
    if (convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)
                (activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

        convertView = li.inflate(
                R.layout.row_student, null);
       itemHolder.textViewStudent = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvstudentname);
        convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
        itemHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        itemHolder = (StudentAdapter.ItemHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    if (studentBeanList != null && !studentBeanList.isEmpty())
    {
        final StudentBean studentBean = studentBeanList.get(position);
        if (studentBean != null) {
            if
                    (itemHolder.textViewStudent != null && studentBean.getStudentname() != null)
            {
               itemHolder.textViewStudent.setText(studentBean.getStudentname());
            }
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
private class ItemHolder {
    TextView textViewStudent;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Your code to nofify
}
}
```

I am inflating below XML..

**row_student.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvstudentname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox1" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I am helpless what to do.
How can I get Select All, Select only one (I mean when user select one, other dis selects auto), Select All but one by one. Thanks in Advance..

**This Is new Code**

```
 public class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Activity activity;
private StudentBean studentBean;
private List<StudentBean> studentBeanList;
public StudentAdapter(Activity activity, List<StudentBean> studentBeanList){
    super();
    this.studentBeanList = studentBeanList;
    this.activity = activity;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return studentBeanList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return studentBeanList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    StudentAdapter.ItemHolder itemHolder= new StudentAdapter.ItemHolder();
    if (convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)
                (activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

        convertView = li.inflate(
                R.layout.row_student, null);

        itemHolder.textViewStudent = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvstudentname);
        convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
        itemHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
        itemHolder.checkBox.setChecked(studentBean.isChecked());
        itemHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                studentBean.setChecked(holder.checkBox.isChecked());
            }
        });
    }

    else

    {
        itemHolder = (StudentAdapter.ItemHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    if (studentBeanList != null && !studentBeanList.isEmpty())
    {
        final StudentBean studentBean = studentBeanList.get(position);
        if (studentBean != null) {
            if
                    (itemHolder.textViewStudent != null && studentBean.getStudentname() != null)
            {
                itemHolder.textViewStudent.setText(studentBean.getStudentname());
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ItemHolder {
    TextView textViewStudent;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Your code to nofify
}
```

}

Comment: Did you set android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" in listview ?

Comment: Reference Link : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: I have checked for both with this ,android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" and without this. In both of the cases, listview automatically select more than one checkboxes in a single click.

Comment: all the boxes or some of them?

Comment: If i m selecting one checkbox, after that when i am scrolling down, it appears  other boxes automatically selected. 3 or four boxes as I have 60 Items in Listview

Answer (score 0):

for this you add one Boolean field in **StudentBean** pojo class and make getter setter for that default Boolean is false.

```
private boolean checked = false;
   public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
```

now add below code in your adapter

```
 itemHolder.checkBox.setChecked(studentBean.isChecked());
 itemHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                studentBean.setChecked(holder.checkBox.isChecked());
            }
        });
```

it's work fine and proper.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean att.att.att.com.attendance.bean.StudentBean.isChecked()' on a null object reference
                      at att.att.att.com.attendance.adapter.StudentAdapter.getView(StudentAdapter.java:65)                                                              It is showing this Error

Comment: @ArjunSingh pls share your new code where you add that line

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Activity activity;
private boolean multiSelection = true;
private int selectedPosition = -1;
private List<StudentBean> studentBeanList;
public StudentAdapter(Activity activity, List<StudentBean> studentBeanList){
    this.studentBeanList = studentBeanList;
    this.activity = activity;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return studentBeanList.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return studentBeanList.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemHolder itemHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)
                (activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_student, null);
        itemHolder = new StudentAdapter.ItemHolder();
        itemHolder.textViewStudent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvstudentname);
        itemHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
    } else {
        itemHolder = (StudentAdapter.ItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    itemHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
            int pos = (Integer) cb.getTag();
            StudentBean studentBean = studentBeanList.get(pos);
            studentBean.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
            if(!multiSelection && selectedPosition != -1){
                StudentBean previousStudentBean = studentBeanList.get(selectedPosition);
                previousStudentBean.setChecked(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                selectedPosition = pos;
            }
        }
    });
    if (studentBeanList != null && !studentBeanList.isEmpty()) {
        StudentBean studentBean = studentBeanList.get(position);
        if (studentBean != null) {
            if (itemHolder.textViewStudent != null && studentBean.getStudentname() != null) {
                itemHolder.textViewStudent.setText(studentBean.getStudentname());
                itemHolder.checkBox.setChecked(studentBean.isChecked());
            }
        }
    }
    itemHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);
    return convertView;
}
private class ItemHolder {
    TextView textViewStudent;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Your code to notify
}
public void selectAll() {
    multiSelection = true;
    for(int i=0; i<studentBeanList.size(); i++){
        studentBeanList.get(i).setChecked(true);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void changeSelectMode(boolean enableMultiSelection){
    multiSelection = enableMultiSelection;
}
}
```

You need to have something in your Activity/Fragment for "Select All" and "Change Select Mode". I have a blog about ListView, http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/

Hope this help!